# Python, why does this sum function not work

Tags: python

Why does this sum  function not work? It's intent is to sum the variable items in a list

```
    def sum_list (a_list):
        length= len(a_list)
        counter = 0
        total= 0

        while(counter < length):

             (a_list[counter] +total)          
             total = total + counter
        counter = counter + 1
        return total      



#testing the functions
my_list = [3,3,3]
print sum_list(my_list)
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using the builtin `sum` function?

Comment: What's the error message you get?  What do you think that error message means?

Comment: It would help if this code was even formatted correctly. If you're attempting to execute this python code exactly the way as it's written here, you're going to get errors due to the terrible tab-job that was done.

Comment: You need to indent your code properly. Besides that, please make it look less horrible: Get rid of the useless parens around thr while criterion, do not put random statements into parens, use `x += y` instead of `x = x + y` and do not shadow builtins (i.e. don't call a variable `list`; use `lst` or something like that instead)

Comment: @Michael: Even with the indentation fixed, `length` is still undefined.

Comment: @Sven: I notice that now, but originally I didn't even get to that point because it wouldn't matter since the interpreter couldn't parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `length` is not defined anywhere, but you are trying to use it in the while condition.  That would cause the error you are probably seeing.  The length of your list can be obtained with `len(list)`.

Second, your while body isn't actually using the list values: `(list[counter] +total)` isn't doing anything, as it's not assigned to anything.

Finally, `total = total + counter` isn't adding the values, instead, it's adding the positions of each value.  So, in this example: `0 + 1 + 2`, which , if you fix the `length` problem I mentioned first, you'd end up with `3`, instead of the correct value of `9`.

**Update**

Finally (again), you are not even testing the function with your `my_list = [3,3,3]`, there's no mention of the function you defined above.  Instead, you're just creating a list.